# What H-bridge do I need for my setup?

Tags: voltage, power, dc-motor, h-bridge, lipo

For a home pet project I want to wire up an electro motor to a Raspberry Pi. I want to constantly reverse the direction of the motor (meaning I want to be able to change the direction of the motor about every second). As far as I understand this can only be done with brushed DC electro motors. Since I need quite some power, I was thinking of buying

## 1. Motor

[this electro motor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/200W-DC-motor-is-reversing-24V-speed-control-motor-1800-rpm-high-torque-micro-motor/32738235908.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10000074_10000032_119_10000025_10000029_10000028_10060_10000067_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10059_10099_10000022_10000013_10103_10102_10000016_10096_10000018_10000019_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10107_10050_10106_10051_10000053_10000007_10000050_10084_10083_10000047_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10115_10000041_10000044_10078_10079_10000038_10073_10000035_10121,searchweb201603_10,afswitch_3,single_sort_1_default&btsid=3aba377e-7d40-46d9-b737-c01129578b6a), which is described as:

```
200W DC motor is reversing 24V speed control motor 1800 rpm high torque micro motor
```

[image]

## 2. Battery pack

I then want to wire it up to [this LiPO battery pack](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/12V-24V-18V19V-20V-17AH-52000MAH-LiPO-batteries-with-FREE-6AH-voltage-regulator-30-plugs/32784970173.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10000074_10000032_119_10000025_10000029_10000028_10060_10000067_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10059_10099_10000022_10000013_10103_10102_10000016_10096_10000018_10000019_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10107_10050_10106_10051_10000053_10000007_10000050_10084_10083_10000047_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10115_10000041_10000044_10078_10079_10000038_10073_10000035_10122_10121,searchweb201603_10,afswitch_3,single_sort_1_default&btsid=1d8a28e1-093c-4a70-b659-4fde4b66f9c7), which has the following description:

```
Output voltage:12V-24V
Input voltage: 12.6V
Input current: 1AH-2AH
Output current: Max. 6AH
Output power: Max. 110WH
Material: Li-polymer for PHILIPS 2900MAH batteries 
Capacity: 52000MAH(3.7V)
```

### [EDIT]

@MarceloEspinozaVargas told me in his answer that the battery pack has a regulator which is too weak. So how about I buy two of [these battery packs](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Lipo-Battery-Portable-4800mAh-DC-12V-12-6V-Super-Rechargeable-Pack-EU-US-plug-adaptor-for/32759952263.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10000074_10000032_119_10000025_10000029_10000028_10060_10000067_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10059_10099_10000022_10000013_10103_10102_10000016_10096_10000018_10000019_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10107_10050_10106_10051_10000053_10000007_10000050_10084_10083_10000047_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10115_10000041_10000044_10078_10079_10000038_10073_10000035_10122_10121,searchweb201603_10,afswitch_3,single_sort_1_default&btsid=04d5f97d-927b-4385-9ed8-2f1f2fdbb9a1) (2*12V), serially linking them up so that I get 24V, and then using [this regulator](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/DC-DC-Automatic-Boost-Buck-Converter-8V-30V-to-2V-16V-6A-80W-CC-CV-Voltage/32766563198.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10000074_10000032_119_10000025_10000029_10000028_10060_10000067_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10059_10099_10000022_10000013_10103_10102_10000016_10096_10000018_10000019_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10107_10050_10106_10051_10000053_10000007_10000050_10084_10083_10000047_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10115_10000041_10000044_10078_10079_10000038_10073_10000035_10122_10121,searchweb201603_10,afswitch_3,single_sort_1_default&btsid=ffcea20a-4fec-428d-88f3-c64d7fd7a0c9), which says it is a `DC-DC Automatic Boost Buck Converter 8V-30V to 2V-16V 6A 80W CC/CV Voltage Regulator charging 5v 12v 24v 19v Car power supply`. Would that work you think?

## 3. H-Bridge

I then want to use [this H-bridge](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Double-BTS7960-43A-H-bridge-High-power-Motor-Driver-module-smart-car/32669153168.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_10000074_10000032_119_10000025_10000029_10000028_10060_10000067_10062_10056_10055_10000062_10054_10059_10099_10000022_10000013_10103_10102_10000016_10096_10000018_10000019_10000056_10000059_10052_10053_10107_10050_10106_10051_10000053_10000007_10000050_10084_10083_10000047_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10115_10000041_10000044_10078_10079_10000038_10073_10000035_10122_10121,searchweb201603_10,afswitch_3,single_sort_1_default&btsid=1de9d5c2-fd13-4707-8429-5b99e611c9a3) for reversing the motor direction, which comes with the following info (description below picture):

[image]

```
Double BTS7960 43A H-bridge High-power Motor Driver module:
BTS7960B H-bridge 43A high-power motor driver Module Overview:
This driver uses chips BTS7960 composed of high-power drive full H-bridge driver module 
with thermal over-current protection. Double BTS7960 H-bridge driver circuit, with a 
strong drive and braking, effectively isolating the microcontroller and motor driver! 
High-current 43A

Features:
Double BTS7960 large current (43 A) H bridge driver;
5V isolate with MCU, and effectively protect MCU;
5V power indicator on board;
voltage indication of motor driver output end;
can solder heat sink;
Just need four lines from MCU to driver module (GND. 5V. PWM1. PWM2);
isolation chip 5 V power supply (can share with MCU 5 V);
size: 4 * 5 * 1.2 cm;
Able to reverse the motor forward, two PWM input frequency up to 25kHZ;
two heat flow passing through an error signal output;
isolated chip 5V power supply (can be shared with the MCU 5V), can also use the on-board 5V supply;
the supply voltage 5.5V to 27V;
```

## My Question

Before spending the money on it, I want to be sure that this combination will actually work. I mean; does that seem like a good battery pack for that motor, and can the H-bridge I link to handle the power going through? I see the H-Bridge says

I'm just a bit insecure about spending all this money when it's not going to work. So all tips are welcome!

Comment: I don't speak Spanish very well so the link is fairly useless to me but I would urge you to NOT buy anything that doesn't have a recognizable data sheet and a recognizable supplier. As for "constantly reverse the direction of the motor" you need to define this in a much more clear cut way.

Comment: @Andyaka - Which website opens in Spanish for you? All of them open in English for me. About the `constantly reverse the direction of the motor`; I mean that I want to be able to change the direction of the motor about every one or two seconds to balance something.

Comment: Motor: 200 W motor de la CC es de marcha atrás 24 V de control de velocidad del motor 1800 rpm high torque micro motor

Comment: Data sheets are needed, not buying pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last edit, your battery pack is not a 12V battery, it's an array of 18 3.7V cells that give you 54000mAh with 3.7V output, the regulator it has is actually a step up regulator, so it converts your 3.7V in a 12-24Vdc, what you would need us a step up regulator that can boost 3.7V into 24V with at least 20A

Comment: Alright thank you very much. I just added a different suggestion for a regulator under [EDIT] under point 2. Do you think that would work? And do you think the H-bridge is ok?

Comment: The H Bridge seems OK, but I don't think it could handle that much power (24V*20A aprox 480W) without a cooling fan at least.

Comment: For the new battery pack, it's a 12V 4.8Ah LiIon pack, so the max amount of current you could get from them is 4.8A, since it doesn't tell the maximum discharge capability we asume a 1C of discharge. You might look for battery packs for RC that are capable of release 20C to even 100C of discharge ratio

Comment: Alright thank you. I'll look for one. And do you think the H-bridge is ok for the motor?

Comment: It looks OK, I'll check the datasheet of the BTS7960 (you should take a look too http://www.robotpower.com/downloads/BTS7960_v1.1_2004-12-07.pdf) and come with a better answer

Comment: Wow, that datasheet is a bit too much for me. I'm totally lost in there. I think I'm going to buy the motor and the H-Bridge, and search around for a different battery and regulator (unless you tell me not to do that). While developing my Robot I can of course still use a wire for powering it. Thanks a million, and if you still have tips or info that is still more than welcome!

Comment: At first it looks too much, once you start to read a lot of datasheets you'll start to be able to search exatcly what you're looking for.

Comment: As for the motor and the H-Bridge, the BTS7960 has a thermal resistance of 1ºC/W, so with the best heatsink and a 25ºC ambient temperature it would deliver 125W max, so for your application you must use a fan to dissipate the heat from the heat sink

Comment: One more question; this H-bridge says "Arduino" on top of it. Do you think it will also work with a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I haven't used Raspberry Pi yet but if the logic outputs of you uC are 5V you shouldn't have any troubles with it

Answer (score 1):

Based on the products description, the motor can easily draw more than 13A when using with load, that exceeds a lot the maximum current of your regulator (6A), besides the motor description doesn't show the stall torque and current, and it might be a lot more than 13A, so that regulator is not going to drive the motor unless the motor carries an extremely low load (in which case you'd better go for a smaller motor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how about I use a different battery pack with a different regulator which can handle a higher Amperage. I added a description above in my question under point 2. Do you think that would work?

Comment: You're always welcome. I posted another answer to this question, check it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually going to buy something, buy a professional servi drive with a servo motor. It will be so much more fun! If you need something cheap, take qs9 from here:http://www.adtechen.com/news/QS9-Series-High-performance-Servo-Drives.html. i think it's best calue for money- chinese servo with world level performance.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Any idea where I can buy those online?

Comment: This specific device- probably only from Adtech website. But there are more.

Comment: But a servo motor is going slow, but with a lot of torque right? I need at least 1000rpm, so I don't think a servo motor is good for me. Or am I wrong and can a servo motor actually do a high rpm as well? I'm all up for buying something professional, but I have no clue which ones are professional, so any more tips or links are welcome!

Comment: Not sure about servo at tour place, thus specific worked well on 10000rpm in my lab.

Comment: You probably refer to stepper, it's something different